Is there any tool to create a resizable *viewport* to another window?
Normally, when you resize an application window, the size change is notified to the application and its state and layout change:

I want to somehow resize an application without changing its state/layout.
One possible way is to create a resizable viewport to another window, but is there any tool for it?
My current workaround is to use OBS and its "capture window" functionality (possibly with projector preview option). The downside is it's overkill and at most one viewport can be created.

